# exif.js using old file

Tags: javascript, exif, exif-js

I implemented an EXIF button in a gallery to read EXIF data using the well-known `exif.js` script from [here](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js). My image loads into a `img0` img node, and then I use:

```
function exif() {
  EXIF.getData(img0, function() {
   var model    = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
   var datetime = EXIF.getTag(this, "DateTimeOriginal");
   var fnumber  = EXIF.getTag(this, "FNumber");

   .... <print this.src, and the exif output>

  });
}
```

When I click a thumbnail, the large image appears fullscreen (in a `modal`, with the `img0` img node on it with the corresponding `img.src`), with an EXIF button (top, second from left), which executes the above function exif() when `onclick`. It works fine. Then I close the image by clicking on it, click on another thumbnail, and a second large image opens (with an updated `img.src`). When I click the EXIF button again, I can see a different img.src, yet the same EXIF as the first one (same gps, same time, etc). Somehow exif.js keeps the old img.src, and does not update it. You can check the gallery working [here](https://luis.impa.br/photo/galsearch.html?s=sai,ferr).

How do I force exif.js to see the new img.src file? Is it using the img in the cache? Can I ask exif.js to read the file instead of the `img` node? This is not supported in the documentation.

**EDIT:** I read the exif.js code, and there is a function that checks if the img node has exif:

```
function imageHasData(img) {return !!(img.exifdata); }
```

This function is called just before `getImageData`:

```
if (!imageHasData(img)) { getImageData(img, callback); } else...
```

Therefore, for some reason, `imageHasData(img)` returns `false` the first time and `true` the second.

Comment: You have to update the variable `img0` somehow

Comment: `img0` is the node. What I do is update its `img0.src`. Maybe I should remove and add again the `img0` node... Placing some console.log around the exif.js, I see that the function `getImageData` is executed only for the first image.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the exif.js code I realized which the problem was (see the **EDIT**). The `img` node has the `src` property, but also a new `exifdata` one added by `exif.js`. When closing the image, I did a `img.src = ""`, but I did not erase `img.exifdata`.

So, now when I close the image I do:

```
img.src = "";
delete img.exifdata;
```

Now the problem went away, and the new exif is properly loaded.

Comment: Good that you found a solution! But since you are mutating nodes manually you'll probably have more errors and unpredictable behaviour. So maybe you should rethink the design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yet, I am running my gallery for several years without problems. This just appeared now because I added the exif info. It was my first try with exif.js. If I found some new issue, I will report back.